# How to move emails into Custom Post Type?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, custom-post-type

I found this PHP code to extract the emails. Now, I want to move this email into Custom Post type in WordPress. I have created the custom post type name as  E-mail Inboxes.
Here is the code below of how I extracted the emails:

```
class Email_reader {

    // imap server connection
    public $conn;

    // inbox storage and inbox message count
    private $inbox;
    private $msg_cnt;

    // email login credentials
    private $server = 'myserver.com';
    private $user   = 'myserver@mail.com';
    private $pass   = 'PASSWORD';
    private $port   = 993; // adjust according to server settings

    // connect to the server and get the inbox emails
    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
        $this->inbox();
    }

    // close the server connection
    function close() {
        $this->inbox = array();
        $this->msg_cnt = 0;

        imap_close($this->conn);
    }

    // open the server connection
    // the imap_open function parameters will need to be changed for the particular server
    // these are laid out to connect to a Dreamhost IMAP server
    function connect() {
        $this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.'/notls}', $this->user, $this->pass);
    }

    // move the message to a new folder
    function move($msg_index, $folder='INBOX.Processed') {
        // move on server
        imap_mail_move($this->conn, $msg_index, $folder);
        imap_expunge($this->conn);

        // re-read the inbox
        $this->inbox();
    }

    // get a specific message (1 = first email, 2 = second email, etc.)
    function get($msg_index=NULL) {
        if (count($this->inbox) <= 0) {
            return array();
        }
        elseif ( ! is_null($msg_index) && isset($this->inbox[$msg_index])) {
            return $this->inbox[$msg_index];
        }

        return $this->inbox[0];
    }

    // read the inbox
    function inbox() {
        $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);

        $in = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
            $in[] = array(
                'index'     => $i,
                'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
                'body'      => imap_body($this->conn, $i),
                'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
            );
        }

        $this->inbox = $in;
    }

}
$emails = new Email_reader;


echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($emails);
```

Now I want to add this email to my WordPress Custom Post Type.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a CPT, you can insert instances of that CPT using [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/). If you have custom metadata for each instance you can use [`update_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I'd say you are looking for a email service frontend or Web-UI. Some exist, but those are applications, nothing trivial. I do not see how you could use a email client class as a "page" or "post" in a CMS system. You need some UI logic between the two.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total =  $emails->total_msg(); 

    for ($j=1; $j <= $total; $j++) { 
       $mail =  $emails->get($j);

$post_array = array( 
        'post_content'  => $mail['body'],
        'post_title'    => $mail['header']->subject,
        'post_type'     => 'faqpress_email',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'meta_input'    => array(
            'from'      => $mail['header'] ->fromaddress,
            'email_date'=> $mail['header'] ->Date,   // add post meta as many as you want
            'ticket_id' => $mail['header']->Msgno,
            ),
       );
         wp_insert_post($post_array); 
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).